ebpf compare two dynamic sized strings
...
#define PATH_SEGMENT_LEN 255
typedef unsigned char path_segment[PATH_SEGMENT_LEN];
...
path_segment *a = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&cpu_buffer, &j);
if (!a)
    break;

path_segment *b = current_element->path_elements[i];
...

I need to know if a and b are equal, which both are dynamically sized. I tried __builtin_memcmp but that still returns false even though the strings are equal. The compiler doesn't seem to like a dynamic size for it because it cannot link it when I do that?
if (__builtin_memcmp(*a, *b, PATH_SEGMENT_LEN) == 0)
{
    bpf_printk("%s equals %s", a, b);
    is_relevant = true;
}
else
{
    bpf_printk("%s not equals %s", a, b);
    is_relevant = false;
}

This still tells me that / is not equal to /, when I set the size to 1 then / does equal /, so there is something else in the 254 bytes that doesn't line up?
*a comes from a bpf_probe_read_kernel_str stored in a BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY
*b comes from current_element which is a argument from bpf_for_each_map_elem which loops over an BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY
Is it possible to compare two dynamically sized strings?
EDIT:
I tried the for loop approach:
path_segment *a = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&cpu_buffer, &j);
if (!a)
{
break;
}
    
path_segment *b = current_element->path_elements[i];
    
for (unsigned int o = 0; o < PATH_SEGMENT_LEN; o++)
{
   unsigned char x = *a[2];
   if (x == '\0')
   {
      break;
   }
   bpf_printk("%c", x);
}

which results in:
125: (bf) r6 = r0                     ; frame1: R0_w=map_value_or_null(id=4,map=cpu_buffer,ks=4,vs=255) R6_w=map_value_or_null(id=4,map=cpu_buffer,ks=4,vs=255) cb
; if (!a)
126: (15) if r6 == 0x0 goto pc+12     ; frame1: R6_w=map_value(map=cpu_buffer,ks=4,vs=255) cb
127: (b7) r7 = 255                    ; frame1: R7=255 cb
; unsigned char x = *a[2];
128: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r6 +510)
invalid access to map value, value_size=255 off=510 size=1
R6 min value is outside of the allowed memory range

I see it tries to access offset 510 instead of 2, so it's doing 255*2 instead of just 2. How do I make it so it access offset 2?


This still tells me that / is not equal to /, when I set the size to 1 then / does equal /, so there is something else in the 254 bytes that doesn't line up?

Yes, there could be anything in that buffer after your string (unless you zeroed the buffer first, but that doesn't seem to be the case).

Strncmp Solution
As @0___________ noted, strcmp would be a better match than memcmp here, to take the \0 into account when comparing strings. Unfortunately, that isn't available in eBPF programs.
Instead, if your kernel and program type support it, you may be able to use the bpf_strncmp helper:

long bpf_strncmp(const char *s1, u32 s1_sz, const char *s2)

Description Do strncmp() between s1 and s2. s1 doesn't need to be null-terminated and s1_sz is the maximum storage size of s1. s2 must be a read-only string.
Return An integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first s1_sz bytes of s1 is found to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

As stated above, s2 must be a read-only string. That means you will need to:

Set the BPF_F_RDONLY_PROG flag at creation time.
Freeze the map from userspace after updating it, with the BPF_MAP_FREEZE bpf(2) command.


Native eBPF Solution
If that helper isn't supported in your case or if you can't freeze the map, you will then have to re-implement it in BPF with a loop.
Depending on your kernel version, there are several options available to implement loops in eBPF, from bpf_loop to bpf_for and cond_break. I'd recommend to check the kernel samples and selftests for examples.

Thanks! I tried strncmp but I get "R1 does not point to a read only map", tried to make that map read only by setting the flag BPF_F_RDONLY but that did not resolve it. I also tried a for loop but I get into "R6 min value is outside of the allowed memory range" errors. I added my for loop attempt to the question.

That's because you also need to freeze the BPF map for it to be considered a read-only map. I've extended my answer to cover that.

If you want to try the native eBPF solution and hit issues, then I'd recommend opening a new StackOverflow question or this is going to become unreadable for others with similar issues.
